# Pandas loop into variables adding suffix and transforming original column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I would like to loop into some variable name and the equivalent column with an added suffix "_plus"

```
#original dataset
raw_data = {'time': [2,1,4,2],
            'zone': [5,1,3,0],
           'time_plus': [5,6,2,3],
            'zone_plus': [0,9,6,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['time','zone','time_plus','zone_plus'])
df

#desired dataset
df['time']=df['time']*df['time_plus']
df['zone']=df['zone']*df['zone_plus']
df
```

I would like to do the multiplication in a more elegant way, through a loop, since I have many variables with this pattern: original name * transformed variable with the _plus suffix

something similar to this or better

```
my_list=['time','zone']

for i in my_list:
    df[i]=df[i]*df[i+"_plus"]
```

Comment: What is your question? Because seems you have found a solution.

Comment: please read my full text "I would like to do the multiplication in a more elegant way, through a loop, since I have many variables with this pattern: original name * transformed variable with the _plus suffix". I resolved it but only in manual way, I have many variables, this suggests a loop

Comment: I see that your question has not to do with multiplication, but rather how to list the columns whose name follows a certain pattern ("_plus" pattern). There are answers for this already, using regex or even 'c.endswith("_plus")' which is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
for c in df.filter(regex=r".*(?<!_plus)$", axis=1):
    df[c] *= df[c + "_plus"]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   time  zone  time_plus  zone_plus
0    10     0          5          0
1     6     9          6          9
2     8    18          2          6
3     6     0          3          5
```

---

Or:

```py
for c in df.columns:
    if not c.endswith("_plus"):
        df[c] *= df[c + "_plus"]
```

Comment: Suggesting some alternatives which are similar : `df.assign(**{i:df.filter(like=i).prod(1) for i in my_list})` or `df.assign(**{i:df.loc[:,(i,f"{i}_plus")].prod(1) for i in my_list})` for a new copy. probably `reindex(my_list,axis=1)` later if we dont want the `_plus` columns

Answer (score 2):

```
raw_data = {'time': [2,1,4,2],
        'zone': [5,1,3,0],
       'time_plus': [5,6,2,3],
        'zone_plus': [0,9,6,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['time','zone','time_plus','zone_plus'])

# Take every column that doesn't have a "_plus" suffix
cols = [i for i in list(df.columns) if "_plus" not in i]

# Calculate new columns
for col in cols:
    df[str(col+"_2")] = df[col]*df[str(col+"_plus")]
```

I decided to create the new columns with a "_2" suffix, this way we don't mess up the original data.

Answer (score 1):

```
for c in df.columns:
    if f"{c}_plus" in df.columns:
        df[c] *= df[f"{c}_plus"]
```